Why we obtain dark fringes in Fresnel's diffraction experiment?
There is only one source of light so technically no interference should happen , when no interference is there then there should only be bright light plane , but somehow dark and white  fringes are obtained , please explain how,in detail

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Photons happily interfere with themselves. No need for more than one source of light.

For interference to occur, light needs to be coherent. Now that is a loaded word, since it has different interpretations classically and quantum mechanically.
Diffraction can be treated classically.
An other caveat: I have seen several pop-sci (read: YouTube) sources calling superposition phenomena, e.g. beating between 2 nearby frequencies: interference. This only causes confusion.
EM waves always undergo superposition. You can listen to radio with the lights on...the MHz and visible waves don't care about each other.
Beating involves nearby frequencies (or wavenumbers) and leads to dynamic phenomena due to superposition--still not interference.
Interference requires a stable phase relationship between to two (at least) signals, and dark bands occur when the two phases differ by 180 degrees: the signals cancel (usually partially).
So that is why there are dark bands in diffraction. If you coherently add all the paths from source to detection, the phasors mostly cancel and you see a dark band.
That is: it's not multiple sources, it's multiple paths that matter.

I got it , But in YDSE (Youngs double slit) , 2 coherent sources are required to cause fringes on the screen, if it only requires multiple path then will we get the ydse result as it is if we use only one source of light , as it will also give multiple path.

@CuriousLearner the two coherent sources are the slits, as far as the screen is concerned.
